# Using strings to list parameters for tikz-cd arrows

Tags: strings, tikz-cd

I'm trying to write some macros for making tikz-cd commutative diagrams. In tikz-cd you can give your arrows options like "bend left" or "dotted", in a comma-delimited list:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document} 

\[ \begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow[bend left, dotted]{r}{f^*} & B 
\end{tikzcd} \]

\end{document}
```

So that works fine! But since I want to write macros, I'd like to do things like put those parameters in a string. So I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\newcommand{\arrowformatting}{bend left, dotted}

\begin{document} 

\[ \begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow[\arrowformatting]{r}{f^*} & B 
\end{tikzcd} \]

\end{document}
```

But this breaks; tikz-cd interprets the entire string as one argument and ignores the comma, giving the error

> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/bend left,
>   dotted' and I  am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

How do I define a string `\arrowformatting` such that tikz-cd will actually interpret the comma correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, but the cure may be worse than the sickness, if you limit yourself to typing it in directly each time.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\newcommand{\arrowformatting}{bend left, dotted}

\begin{document} 

\[ \begin{tikzcd}
    A \expandafter\arrow\expandafter[\arrowformatting]{r}{f^*} & B 
\end{tikzcd} \]

\end{document}
```

Perhaps this alternative would suit, creating `\xarrow`, which expands the next token before issuing an `\arrow`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\edef\arrowformatting{bend left, dotted}
\def\xarrow{\expandafter\arrow\expandafter}

\begin{document} 

\[ \begin{tikzcd}
    A \xarrow[\arrowformatting]{r}{f^*} & B 
\end{tikzcd} \]

\[ \begin{tikzcd}
    A \xarrow{r}{f^*} & B 
\end{tikzcd} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If this latter method proves problematic in the absence of optional arguments (and I don't think it should), here is another form that should be even safer.  However, it requires the syntax

```
A \xarrow\arrowformatting{r}{f^*} & B
```

without brackets around `\arrowformatting`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\edef\arrowformatting{\expandafter[bend left, dotted]}
\def\xarrow{\expandafter\arrow}

\begin{document} 

\[ \begin{tikzcd}
    A \xarrow\arrowformatting{r}{f^*} & B 
\end{tikzcd} \]

\[ \begin{tikzcd}
    A \xarrow{r}{f^*} & B 
\end{tikzcd} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I can see that fixes the example I gave, and I'll try things out tonight to see if it works out with the macro I want to write (and update the question if something else breaks I guess).

Comment: @djc You should be safe if using `\xarrow` only if optional arguments are present (since optional arguments are text), but I don't know enough of `tikz` to know of any cases where it would break if you used `\xarrow` when no optional argument is present.  For it to break, the first item after the `[` or `{` would have to be a macro, and even then, it it is likely to work.

Comment: @djc See revision for even safer alternative.

Comment: Okay, I've been playing around with things and now I'm stuck on what I wanted to do next, which was to make \arrowformatting be something that produced output from string manipulation commands (rather than a fixed string like I was trying to get to work in my question). I guess I was assuming that would just work, but apparently I really don't understand how tex manipulates strings. Anyway, is it better to post a new question or update this one?

Comment: @djc Without knowing more details, I couldn't really say if it would be better to revise the question or make a new one.  I will not be offended whatever you choose.  It is up to you.