# Writing macros for tikz-cd arrow options

Tags: macros, strings, tikz-cd

I'm trying to write a macro to let me write shorthand for tikz-cd arrows. For instance instead of having to write out the full command

```
\arrow[swap, dotted]{r}{f^*}
```

I'd like to have a shorthand like

```
\A[s.]{r}{f^*}
```

where the `\A` command processes the `s` to mean `swap` and the `.` to mean `dotted`. Using the xstring package it was pretty easy to write a command that takes `s.` as an input and outputs `swap,dotted,` but I don't know how to then feed that in as an argument for `\arrow`. I [asked a simpler question earlier today](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170807/using-strings-to-list-parameters-for-tikz-cd-arrows) which I thought would show me how to deal with the problem in general, but it turns out that dealing with how latex expands macros is a lot more complicated than I realized.

Anyway, the code I tried writing (after incorporating Steven B. Segletes's suggestions for how to solve my easier problem) is this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring} 
\usepackage{xifthen}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\arrowformatting}[1]{%
    \IfSubStr{#1}{s}{swap,}{}%
    \IfSubStr{#1}{.}{dotted,}{}%
    % Add more commands here later
}

\newcommand{\A}[3][]{%
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{%
        \arrow{#2}{#3}%
    }{%
        \expandafter\arrow\expandafter[\arrowformatting{#1}]{#2}{#3}%
    }%
}

\begin{document} 

\[ \begin{tikzcd}
    A \A[s.]{r}{f^*} & B 
\end{tikzcd} \]

\end{document}
```

The function `\arrowformatting` works correctly on its own - if I call `\arrowformatting{s.}` in the document it prints out `swap,dotted,` like expected. But if I use the `\A` command as shown, it gives me an error

```
! Argument of \XC@definec@lor has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.29 \end{tikzcd}
                  \]
```

Is there an easy way to fix this and get the output of `\arrowformatting` to be interpreted as input to `\arrow` like I want? Or am I going to run into lots of complicated order-of-expansion issues, and would I be better off trying something else (like I believe there's a package that lets you run python code within latex, and hopefully that could generate the correct `\arrow` command I want)?

Comment: In terms of your actual question, it is relevant that the macros of the `xstring` package are not purely expandable, so simply playing with the order of expansion will not suffice here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish something similar to this by creating TikZ styles called `s` and `.`:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt,convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{commutative diagrams/.cd, 
    s/.style = {swap},
    ./.style = {dotted},
    s./.style = {s,.}
    }
\newcommand{\A}{\ar}

\begin{document}

% Two different keys, separated by commas:
\begin{tikzcd}
A \ar[s,.]{r}{f^*} & B
\end{tikzcd}

% A single, specially defined key `s.`:
\begin{tikzcd}
A \A[s.]{r}{f^*} & B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

I also created a style called `s.` to demonstrate that such a thing is possible. However, this is not a practical way to omit the commas if you want to be able to handle all possible permutations of more than two or three abbreviation keys.

The output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That seems like a nice and easy alternative solution - I didn't realize you could make your own styles in tikzcd. I'm still a bit curious whether it's possible to make what I wanted to do work

Comment: I'd also be interested to see a solution to that. I've tried before to work one out, but have been unable to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a little late, but using `/utils/exec=` and `\pgfkeysalso` you can get what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\arrowformatting}[1]{%
    \IfSubStr{#1}{s}{\pgfkeysalso{swap}}{}%
    \IfSubStr{#1}{.}{\pgfkeysalso{dotted}}{}%
    % Add more commands here later
}

\newcommand{\A}[3][]{%
        \arrow[/utils/exec=\arrowformatting{#1}]{#2}{#3}%
}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{tikzcd}
    A \A[s.]{r}{f^*} & B
\end{tikzcd} \]

\end{document}
```