# Reduce source code of different tcolorbox macros

Tags: macros, tcolorbox

in my book I have a lot of tcolorboxes to use. They are slightly different so I added a macro that decides depending on the arguments, which tcolorbox to draw. 
Obviously that produces a LOT of source code (one command per tcolorbox).

So I tried to reduce it but it doesn't work properly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{mp}{RGB}{240,240,240} % Farbe für + -

\newlength{\bs}\setlength{\bs}{30pt} % Basislänge   
\newlength{\ns}

\newcommand{\iround}{
                interior titled code={
                    \fill[mp,rounded corners=15pt]
                        ([xshift=-1pt,yshift=-10pt]interior.west)
                        rectangle
                        ([xshift=\ns,yshift=3pt]title.north west); 
                    \draw[rounded corners=15pt,color=mp, line width=1pt,fill=white]
                        (frame.south west) -- 
                        (title.south west) -- 
                        (title.south east) --
                        (frame.south east) -- cycle;}
}

\newcommand{\ibs}[3]{\scantokens{%
        \setlength{\ns}{\widthof{#1}+\bs}
            \begin{tcolorbox}[   
                arc=15pt,
                outer arc=15pt,
                title=#1,
                coltitle=black,
                enhanced,
                freelance,
                frame code={},
                \iround
            ]
            \raggedright #2
            \end{tcolorbox}}}


\begin{document}

\ibs{title}{A}{B}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works if you say `\newcommand\iround{
  \fill[mp,rounded corners=15pt]
                        ([xshift=-1pt,yshift=-10pt]interior.west)
                        rectangle
                        ([xshift=\ns,yshift=3pt]title.north west); 
                    \draw[rounded corners=15pt,color=mp, line width=1pt,fill=white]
                        (frame.south west) -- 
                        (title.south west) -- 
                        (title.south east) --
                        (frame.south east) -- cycle;
}` and add `interior titled code=\iround` as an option for the `tcolorbox`.

Comment: could you explain why I have to omit the "interior titled code="?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will work if you just leave the `\fill` and `\draw` parts in the definition of `\iround` and move the interior titled code to the argument of `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{mp}{RGB}{240,240,240} % Farbe für + -

\newlength{\bs}\setlength{\bs}{30pt} % Basislänge   
\newlength{\ns}

\newcommand{\iround}{
                    \fill[mp,rounded corners=15pt]
                        ([xshift=-1pt,yshift=-10pt]interior.west)
                        rectangle
                        ([xshift=\ns,yshift=3pt]title.north west); 
                    \draw[rounded corners=15pt,color=mp, line width=1pt,fill=white]
                        (frame.south west) -- 
                        (title.south west) -- 
                        (title.south east) --
                        (frame.south east) -- cycle;
}

\newcommand{\ibs}[3]{\scantokens{% I am not sure why \cantokens was used here
        \setlength{\ns}{\widthof{#1}+\bs}
            \begin{tcolorbox}[   
                arc=15pt,
                outer arc=15pt,
                title=#1,
                coltitle=black,
                enhanced,
                freelance,
                frame code={},
                interior titled code=\iround
            ]
            \raggedright #2
            \end{tcolorbox}}}


\begin{document}

\ibs{title}{A}{B}

\end{document}
```

The reason is an expansion problem, similar to the one present in [Using strings to list parameters for tikz-cd arrows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170807/3954); **Steven B. Segletes** showed in his answer there a possibility using `\expandafter`s that might also work here (I didn't tested it), but I think (as he himself mentioned in his answer) that other approaches (like the ones I propose here) might be safer.

[image]

Another option is to use a style, as in:

```
\tcbset{
iround/.style={
  interior titled code={
                    \fill[mp,rounded corners=15pt]
                        ([xshift=-1pt,yshift=-10pt]interior.west)
                        rectangle
                        ([xshift=\ns,yshift=3pt]title.north west); 
                    \draw[rounded corners=15pt,color=mp, line width=1pt,fill=white]
                        (frame.south west) -- 
                        (title.south west) -- 
                        (title.south east) --
                        (frame.south east) -- cycle;}
  }                        
}
```

and then use this style for the `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{mp}{RGB}{240,240,240} % Farbe für + -

\newlength{\bs}\setlength{\bs}{30pt} % Basislänge   
\newlength{\ns}

\tcbset{
iround/.style={
  interior titled code={
                    \fill[mp,rounded corners=15pt]
                        ([xshift=-1pt,yshift=-10pt]interior.west)
                        rectangle
                        ([xshift=\ns,yshift=3pt]title.north west); 
                    \draw[rounded corners=15pt,color=mp, line width=1pt,fill=white]
                        (frame.south west) -- 
                        (title.south west) -- 
                        (title.south east) --
                        (frame.south east) -- cycle;}
  }                        
}

\newcommand{\ibs}[3]{\scantokens{% I am not sure why \cantokens was used here
        \setlength{\ns}{\widthof{#1}+\bs}
            \begin{tcolorbox}[   
                arc=15pt,
                outer arc=15pt,
                title=#1,
                coltitle=black,
                enhanced,
                freelance,
                frame code={},
                iround
            ]
            \raggedright #2
            \end{tcolorbox}}}


\begin{document}

\ibs{title}{A}{B}

\end{document}
```

Which approach to use will depend on the actual intent; unfortunately, the question doesn't contain enough information of the actual use case to decide which one would be the best alternative here.

Another thing that calls my attention is the use of `\scantokens`; once again the problem is that the MWE posted doesn't give enough information as to decide whether this is really necessary.

Comment: The first one works best. As I have many different styles, I'm using a macro that changes the style depending on the arguments.